# Django - Ajax: 3 requests

Tags: django, django-forms

My view can receive 3 Ajax requests. How can my view differentiate these requests for adapting the treatment?

Actually I did this:

```
if request.POST.__contains__(u'nameOfForm') :
```

'nameOfForm' is send by the request Ajax for identification.

Comment: There's never any reason to use the double-underscore internal methods. That code is spelled `if 'nameOfForm' in request.POST:`. But what is your question?

Comment: How my view can differentiate ajax requests ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't check the existence of one ajax data to differentiate 3 cases, you should give 3 different strings as the value of parameter `nameOfForm` in your ajax data.

Then in your views.py you could use:

```
nameOfForm = request.POST.get('nameOfForm')
```

to get the actual string you passed, after that you could differentiate based on what you get.

Comment: It's proper to differenciate ajax requests like this ?

Comment: @zoulou That's why we need stackoverflow, to put many people's mind together for the best solution. I don't find my method anything weird,  after all, you need something to identify the source, right? Unless somebody point out the flaw of my method, I still think it works pretty well.

Comment: Yes it's right ! Thank you, if I don't find better solution I will use it.